# Selenium (Python) Headless Mode is not working on Chrome Version 113.0.5672.63 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, headless, headless-browser

I am trying to make a bot which login to the instagram and do some stuff. This is a chunk of my code. When i Run this code without headless it works fine. But whenever i use headless. It throws me error, that it is unable to find the CSS SELECTOR. You can find the error in the end of the post.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver

def chrome_settings():
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    driver = uc.Chrome(
          options=chrome_options
       )
    return driver
driver=chrome_settings()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'username').send_keys('myusername')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password').send_keys('mypassword')

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div/label/input')

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[3]/button').click()
```

I want to run this code in headless mode.
Current Chrome Version is 113.0.5672.63 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I am getting this error on digital ocean server (ubuntu), however this code sometimes runs on my laptop and sometimes gives the same error in laptop aswell.

```
File "/opt/temppp/main.py", line 20, in <module>
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'username').send_keys('myusername')
File "/opt/Bodoo-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 831, in find_element
        return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
File "/opt/Bodoo-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/opt/Bodoo-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="username"]"}
      (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.92)
    Stacktrace:
    #0 0x560be4db7133 <unknown>
    #1 0x560be4aeb966 <unknown>
    #2 0x560be4b280dc <unknown>
    #3 0x560be4b28211 <unknown>
    #4 0x560be4b626c4 <unknown>
    #5 0x560be4b47bfd <unknown>
    #6 0x560be4b601c7 <unknown>
    #7 0x560be4b479a3 <unknown>
    #8 0x560be4b1c46a <unknown>
    #9 0x560be4b1d55e <unknown>
    #10 0x560be4d76cae <unknown>
    #11 0x560be4d7a8fe <unknown>
    #12 0x560be4d83f20 <unknown>
    #13 0x560be4d7b923 <unknown>
    #14 0x560be4d4ec0e <unknown>
    #15 0x560be4d9eb08 <unknown>
    #16 0x560be4d9ec97 <unknown>
    #17 0x560be4daf113 <unknown>
    #18 0x7f8a4e090402 <unknown>
```

Comment: What do you define with "doesn't work" ?